# User-friendly names for plotly CSS colors?

Tags: colors, plotly

I know that one can view the plotly default color sequence as:

```
import plotly.express as px

print(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
```

which yields a list of CSS colors:

```
['#636EFA', '#EF553B', '#00CC96', '#AB63FA', '#FFA15A', '#19D3F3', '#FF6692', '#B6E880', '#FF97FF', '#FECB52']
```

I can specify a color in plotly by selecting an element from this list.  For example:

```
go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, line={"color": '#636EFA'})
```

Are there more user-friendly names defined within plotly for these colors, or is CSS color the only way to refer to the them?

Answer (score 8):

I feel you :)

Actually yes!

**1. For "continuous color scales":** (*2. For discrete color scales*)

[image]

**2. For discrete color scales:**

(*Have fun ;)*)

[image]