Border around plotly figure
I have some plotly plots that I like and just need one final piece before I can present them: a border around the entire figure. I have gotten this to work in matplotlib.pyplot via fig.patch.set_linewidth and fig.patch.set_edgecolor, but I have not been successful in plotly.
Is there not just a simple function to add a border around my whole plotly figure like there is in matplotlib?
From the code below, I have this.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x = x, y = y))
fig.show()


What I want it to create something more like this, with a border (not necessarily green) around the very edge of the entire plot.

(I made that border in Paint but cannot do that for every graph I have produced.)
These plots might have to display in Jupyter Notebooks, not just in saved image files.
A discussion on the plotly forum concerns how to get rid of the border, but I do not see how the border got there in the first place, let alone how I could customize the border.

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to draw borders around a figure in Plotly?

@amance That puts the border around the plot, not the entire figure. Is there a modification to push out the border to the entire figure? For instance, I would want the numbers along the axes to be within the borders.

You can add a shape as an annotation with fig.add_shape() and use the paper coordinates to have the outer boundaries encompass around the plot area.
I think this below using your code as a basis gets close to what you added in Paint with the addition of fig.add_shape before fig.show();:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x = x, y = y))
# add a shape based on https://plotly.com/python/shapes/ and https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/ saying "there is a shape equivalent to text annotations."
# needed to get position correct, see https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#adding-annotations-with-xref-and-yref-as-paper and https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/#positioning-with-paper-container-coordinates-or-axis-domain-coordinates
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x0=-0.06, y0=-0.3, x1=1.06, y1=1.3, 
    line=dict(
        #color="RoyalBlue",
        color="limegreen", #named colors from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502441/8508004
        width=2,
    ),
    #fillcolor="LightSkyBlue",
)
fig.show();

Resulting Output

Details
The comments in the code refer to the documentation or StackOverflow questions that aided in adjusting your code to do this. The main thing is that Plotly's documentation page 'Text and Annotations in Python' says, "there is a shape equivalent to text annotations" and links over to the documentation on'Shapes in Python'.
The clue to use the 'paper' coordinates came from that line fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor="#25499F") in the forum post linked by OP.

The image you posted is what I want. I am not getting it to work on my computer. I only get the vertical green lines along the sides, not the horizontal lines at the top and bottom.

you might need to increase your top and bottom margins fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, b=50))

What are you using? I was using fairly current JupyterLab (v4.1.8 at this time) launched from here. You can go there and click 'launch binder' and get a temporary session of your own without logging in. Everything is already installed. My code works there or if you use the Jupyter Notebook v 7.1.3 available in that session, too. (I change the URL to get to it, but at the bottom of the README for the repo I directed you to there is a launch button for going to a Jupyter Notebook interface.)

Amance's idea makes it so I get what Dave describes by default. When I add in fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, b=50)) before fig.show();, I see only the vertical green lines along the sides and not the horizontal lines at the top and bottom. fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=68, b=68)) (or with those values higher, up to 120, worked though).

@amance That did the trick! Is there a way to automatically "crop" away the portion outside of the border?

You can also complement the top and bottom parameters with left and right ones (while using larger numbers as suggested by @Wayne), looks nicer especially on smaller screens:
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=200, b=200, l=150, r=150))
